# Link to marker in leaflet map from extern <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, leaflet

I host a leaflet map and want to link to certain marker on that map from an a-element outside the map. I want the marker to behave like it was clicked, when the link is clicked.

Clicking on

```
<a href="#" onclick="WHATGOESHERE?">My Link</a>
```

should activate my marker

```
L.marker([52.121935,11.627137], {icon: photomarker}).addTo(map)
.bindPopup("<b>This is a marker</b>")  ;
```

How can I achieve that? I got a hint, that it can be done with

```
marker.fire('click')
```

but I dont get it. Where should I put that? I am pretty new to javascript...

You can see the whole map here: http://bit.ly/VtFXFN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save reference

```
var t = L.marker([52.121935,11.627137], {icon: photomarker}).addTo(map)
.bindPopup("<b>This is a marker</b>");
```

in a

```
<a href="#" onclick="t.fire('click')">My Link</a>
```